# Building up subqueries of derived django fields

Tags: django, aggregate-functions, derived

I have a few transformations I need to perform on my table before I aggregate.

I need to multiply transaction_type (which is either 1 or -1) by amount to yield a signed_amount. Then I need to sum all signed_amounts by primary_category (which is a foreign key to secondary category which is a foreign key of my table).

```
DEBIT = -1
CREDIT = 1
TRANSACTION_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    (DEBIT, 'debit'),
    (CREDIT, 'credit'),
)

class Transaction(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    transaction_type = models.IntegerField(choices=TRANSACTION_TYPE_CHOICES)
    secondary_category = models.ForeignKey(Secondary_Category)

class Primary_Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Category Name", max_length=30) 
    category = models.ForeignKey(Primary_Category_Bucket) 

class Secondary_Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Category Name", max_length=30)
    primary_category = models.ForeignKey(Primary_Category)
```

I'm stuck on the first bit though.

```
from django.db.models import Sum, Count, F

original_transactions = Transaction.objects.all()
original_transactions.signed_amount = F('transaction_type') * F('amount')

for transaction in original_transactions:
    print transaction.signed_amount
```

When I try to sanity check that signed_amount is being calculated, I get an error that 'Transaction' object has no attribute 'signed_amount'. I don't want to save signed_amount to the database. I just want to generate it as derived field so I can calculate my totals.

How do I calculate this derived field and subsequently aggregate by primary_category.name?

Answer (score 0):

User python decorator `property` on a method for class `Transaction`:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    transaction_type = models.IntegerField(choices=TRANSACTION_TYPE_CHOICES)
    secondary_category = models.ForeignKey(Secondary_Category)

    @property
    def signed_amount(self):
        return self.amount * self.transaction_type
```

Then for each `Transaction` object you can do `transaction.signed_amount`.

I'm not sure if the aggregation part could be done using queries, but if you don't have that many `PrimaryCategory`, then python would be good enough to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do this.

```
all_transactions = Transaction.objects.all().order_by('secondary_category__primary_category_id')
sum = 0
if all_transactions:
    primary_category_id = all_transactions[0].secondary_category.primary_category_id
    for transaction in all_transactions:
        if primary_category_id == transaction.secondary_category.primary_category_id:
            sum += (transaction.amount * transaction_type)
        else:
            sum = (transaction.amount * transaction_type)
    print sum
```